# Activity no funciona al agregar id a button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Tengo un activity cuyo código xml dejo abajo, el problema es que cuando le agrego un id a un button dentro del xml del activity, de esta manera:

```
 android:id="@+id/pinbutton"
```

El activity ya no levanta y se cierra la aplicación, retorna este error:

```
05-25 18:40:25.645 940-940/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 940: eglCreateSyncKHR(1288): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-25 18:40:25.745 3225-3445/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:40:25.745 3225-3445/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe3896080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-25 18:40:26.715 3023-3023/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
05-25 18:40:26.715 3023-3023/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for net.eqsoft.pacienteapp: Resource ID #0x0
```

Código xml completo:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="net.eqsoft.pacienteapp.ResgistrarActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pinbutton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                android:text="@string/registrar_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Cómo sigo con el mismo problema, y esto no parece ser error en layout, voy a colocar el código java involucrado, quizá aquí esté el error.

Código Java del Activity:

```
package net.eqsoft.pacienteapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ResgistrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resgistrar);
   }
}
```

Y el trozo de código desde donde se lanza el activity como parte de un menu en mi activity principal:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.paciente_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_registrar:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ResgistrarActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case R.id.item_salir:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y tu archivo .java?

Comment: Es de lo más básico ya que recién estaba empezando a programarlo, pero al ir probando me dió este error.

Comment: @manduinca tu mensaje de error no indica nada reelevante, agrega el segmento donde indique algo como "Caused by" =) además te sugiero agregar el código

Comment: prueba de hacer un clean y rebuild

Comment: Parece ser puro capricho del ide, este no es motivo para que una app se cierre, a menos que no existan los recursos que veo en ese botón. Tanto `string`, `style`, `color` está en orden? ¿existen? `borderlessButtonStyle` requiere API 11 o superior

Comment: Sí todo está en orden, gracias por responde. ¿El clean como lo hago?

Comment: Al final, después de revisar y revisar me di cuenta de un error en el Manifest, en la línea que defino el activity principal no cierro la cabecera (osea faltaba un ">"), lo raro es que esto nunca dió error, y no tengo idea en que momento se borró o si estuvo así desde que lo escribí. Bueno arreglé esto y la aplicación corre muy bien. Gracias por guiarme por dónde iba la cosa :)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) para las inyecciones de vista, aparte de ahorrarte codigo lo hace mas rapido y esas molestas lineas de `findViewById()` ya no son necesarias.

Comment: esto debería ser un comentario ya que es más una sugerencia ?

Comment: Hola Moises, como comentario aparte se podría ahorrar código de cuantas lineas? sabes he visto ButterKnife y personalmente no veo una gran ventaja =P además te ahorras lineas pero agregas una librería de más kb de los que tendrías si usaras findViewById() ...

Comment: Pues fijate @Elenasys tienes otras cosas como el Bind de los resurces (drawables, string, colores, dimensiones) y las funciones OnClick, entre otras cosas que estan detalladas en la pagina. Es verdad solo te ayuda a escribir menos pero en mi caso personal escribir menos es ahorrar tiempo.

Comment: @Elenasys no puedo comentar por que me pide mas puntos xD xD

Comment: Ya he visto, trata de participar más o preguntar para obtener más puntos. En cuanto a el uso de las librería creo que es primero evaluar los pros y contras, quiza en un futuro la use en algún proyecto. Saludos!

Comment: Al final, después de revisar y revisar me di cuenta de un error en el Manifest, en la línea que defino el activity principal no cierro la cabecera (osea faltaba un ">"), lo raro es que esto nunca dió error, y no tengo idea en que momento se borró o si estuvo así desde que lo escribí. Bueno arreglé esto y la aplicación corre muy bien. :)

Comment: @manduinca me alegro que lo encontrastes, mira siempre a la banda derecha donde aparecen las lineas de color "warnings" y el mismo Android Studio con alt + intro te muestra como solventar problemas. Por cierto crea una respuesta con tu solución y así podrás cerrar la pregunta como resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando a detalle el mensaje de error se tiene:

> No package identifier when getting value for resource number
>   0x00000000

y

> PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for
>   net.eqsoft.pacienteapp: Resource ID #0x0

Si comentas que al agregar un id en un elemento marca error, probablemente es el 
`tools:context`, que especifica que activity es asociada con el layout.

Asegura que sea en realidad la actividad que carga tu Layout:

```
tools:context="net.eqsoft.pacienteapp.ResgistrarActivity">
```

Tal vez dentro de la activity `ResgistrarActivity` esas cargando otro layout diferente mediante `setContentView()`.

Genera nuevamente tu proyecto 
`Build` > `Rebuild Project`

Comment: Pero en el layout se puede apreciar que eso está bien.

Comment: En verdad únicamente sucede cuando agregas un id al boton?  prueba únicamente con tools:context=".ResgistrarActivity">

Comment: Ahora quee stoy probando, ocurre cada vez que agrego un id, sea a un botón o a un Textview o cualquier otra etiqueta.

Comment: activity_resgistrar.xml es el layout que agregaste a la pregunta?

Comment: Sí, yo también pensé que me había equivocado en escribir, pero había conformidad en todo el documento con ese nombre. Pero por revisar esto me di cuenta de un error en el Manifest, en la línea que defino el activity principal no cierro la cabecera (osea faltaba un ">"), lo raro es que esto nunca dió error, y no tengo idea en que momento se borró o si estuvo así desde que lo escribí. Bueno arreglé esto y la aplicación corre muy bien. :)

Comment: podría decirse que un simple rebuild corrige este detalle, en ocasiones no marca error ya que carga lo que tiene en los .dex, cuando tengas este tipo de error mejor realiza un Build > Clean Project o un Rebuild Project. a mi me ha pasado lo mismo pero con layouts! =(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40400/discussion-between-elenasys-and-manduinca).